# Concordion Unable to find specification

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, concordion

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find specification: com/concordion/Concordion.html
```

I'm using Concordion 2.2.0 with Junit 5 jupiter using the Junit 4 vintage engine and a TFS build agent using maven. The maven surefire picks up the Concordion java file but simply can't find the corresponding Concordion html and so the auto-tests fail.

The html specification file is in the resources directory but it doesn't matter where I put it, the surefire / concordion libraries can't find it!

Comment: Is there a config element to tell Concordion where the html specs are?

Answer (score 0):

The specification files need to be on the classpath in the same package as the Java class. Typically this is under the `src/test/resources` folder. See https://concordion.org/coding/java/markdown/#locating-the-specification for more details.

Are you able to provide a simplified test case showing the issue?

Moving the specifications to the same location as the java files (`src/test/java` or `src/main/java`) should get it working in the short term.